# Verify Cauchy-Schwarz holds for two vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I show that $(\alpha_1 + \alpha_2 + \ldots + \alpha_n)^2 \le n(\alpha_1^2 + \alpha_2^2 + \ldots + \alpha_n^2) \ \text{for} \ \alpha_i \in \bf{R}$?

My hint is to invoke Cauchy-Schwarz with $\bf{x} = (\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \ldots, \alpha_n)^T$ and $\bf{y} = (1, 1, \ldots, 1)^T$.

C-S says that $|\bf{x}^*\bf{y}| \le ||\bf{x}|| \times ||\bf{y}||$.

Comment: The hint is all you need. Write out what $|x\cdot y|$, $||x||$ and $||y||$ are for your vectors and you are done (you might want to square the inequality first).

Comment: Yikes, didn't realize it was that easy.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following quadratic equation $$(a_1^2 + a_2^2 + ... + a_n^2) x^2 + 2(a_1 + a_2 + ... + a_n)x +(1 + 1+ ... + 1) = 0.$$

Apparently, this equation has no more than 1 root since it is the same as $$(a_1x + 1)^2 + (a_2x + 1)^2 + ... (a_nx + 1)^2 = 0.$$

Notice that the left-hand-side of the above equation is non-negative.

Thus we have $$\Delta = b^2 - 4 a c \le 0.$$

Proved.

Comment: Slightly, very slightly confusing at the beginning as it looks like the answerer  confused questions (delete that "apparently"), but this is an excellent answer as it gives a very elementary proof. +1